# scikit learn GridSearchCV always returns the first parameters as best

Tags: scikit-learn

I set parameters for GridSearchCV to be:

```
parameters = {'kernel':['rbf'], 'C':[1, 5, 0.5], 'gamma':[1, 5, 0.5]}
grid = GridSearchCV(SVC(), parameters)
grid.fit(dataset, targets)
```

Then `grid.best_params_` or `grid.best_estimator_` always returns the first parameters from the list to be the best (i.e. 1 and 1). If I change the order of the parameters and put 5 at the top of the list for 'C', then the best parameters are 'C'=5 and 'gamma'=1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly there is no change in the scores between the parameters. Have you looked at the ``grid_scores_`` attribute or set the verbosity parameter? This can happen in particular with a small dataset. Also, you parameters are very close together.

Comment: Did you find any solution because I am struggling with the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the scoring parameter to (roc_auc), her's an example:

```
    grid = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid = p, scoring='roc_auc')
    grid.fit(self.train_data, self.train_labels)
    print('\nThe best hyper-parameter for -- {} is {}, the corresponding mean accuracy through 10 Fold test is {} \n'\
        .format(name, grid.best_params_, grid.best_score_))
    model = grid.best_estimator_
    train_pred = model.predict(self.train_data)
    print('{} train accuracy = {}\n'.format(name,(train_pred == self.train_labels).mean()))
```

Comment: By using scoring getting this error `raise ValueError("{0} format is not supported".format(y_type)) ValueError: multiclass format is not supported`